# How can i do "where and include" query?

Tags: laravel

I have a table called `loan_tenors` where there is 2 columns defined, `company_id` and `is_global`. I want to make a query by this condition:

> Get all `loan_tenors` where `company_id` is equals to the user's company id, but also include the data where `is_global` is `true` eventhough the `company_id` value is different.

Is there any way to achieve this condition? I've tried this query but the result is not what i wanted.

`MyController.php`

```php
// This only returns one matches condition
LoanTenor::whereCompanyId($request->user()->company_id)
    ->orWhereIsGlobal(true)
    ->get();

// This one is the same
LoanTenor::whereCompanyId($request->user()->company_id)
    ->whereIsGlobal(true)
    ->get();

// This one either
LoanTenor::where(function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->whereCompanyId($request->user()->company_id)
            ->whereIsGlobal(false);
    })
    ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('company_id', '!=', $request->user()->company_id)
            ->whereIsGlobal(true);
    })
    ->get();
```

**EDIT**

To make it clear, please have a look at this link, please note that i'm logged in as a user with `company_id` = 2

[link to the result & the expected query result (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/qFmSXqBz)

Comment: `LoanTenor::where('company_id', $request->user()->company_id)
    ->where('global', 'true')
    ->get();`

Comment: @sta it has to be orWhere i think

Comment: @sta It is only giving me the global data.

Comment: you have to use `orWhere('global'..`

Comment: Did you check `dd($request->user()->company_id);`??  Whats the output

Comment: @sta , @user3532758 , i don't do `dd` but here is the json result from the query. I also wrote what i expecting on it below the query result, please have a look. https://pastebin.com/qFmSXqBz

Comment: oh, you tell me to dd the company id, it is 2 since i logged in with an account that has a company with id = 2

Comment: @DonnyPratama did you try this query: `LoanTenor::where('company_id', $request->user()->company_id)     ->orWhere('global', 'true')     ->get();` this is @sta's query but with orWhere for the second where?

Comment: Whats about with this? `LoanTenor::where('company_id', 2)->where('global', 1) ->get();`

Comment: @user3532758 if where condition not match, then the orWhere will work. Otherwise not.

Comment: `where` in both is equivalent to `WHERE company_id = 2 AND is_glabal = true`

Comment: @user3532758 , yes, the result is just the same.. @ sta, the other tenors dissapears, it only shows the data with the same company id, i want the global data to keep showing but prevent user for getting the other companies's tenors which is marked as not global.

Comment: Can you log the query it produced? enableQuery log and see if it produces an OR instead of the AND when using orWhere. (or your first query because that is definitely the logic' Should be `where company_id = 2 OR is_global = 1`

Comment: sorry, i forgot to login using the 2nd account, here is the right log https://pastebin.com/XjPzL4UW

Comment: That is the right query, and it should give you all tenors with company id `1` (binding says comapny id 1) and all other tenors where global is set to 1.

Comment: if you are not getting the right results, there must be something else thats messing up the result. Can you test that query in a mysql client and see if it gives the right results

Comment: okay, let me try that in a moment

Comment: it works! hmm, i think you're right, i made some mistake in my controller. :/ ..thanks for your help anyway.. :D

Comment: @user3532758 your comment solved the issue, so post this comment as an answer

Comment: @sta nah it's ok, there was nothing wrong with OP's query after all.

Comment: @user3532758 StackOverfolw is line an encyclopedia. So it may help somone, who face the same issue and find this question

Answer (score 0):

```
$data1 = LoanTenor::where('company_id',$request->user()->company_id)
  ->where('is_global','true')
  ->get();
$data2 = LoanTenor::where('company_id','!=',$request->user()->company_id)
  ->where('is_global','true')
  ->get();
$merged = $data2->merge($data1);
$result = $merged->all();
```

Comment: While this answer may solve the OP's issue, please, provide an explanation what does your code do in order to make this more understandable for people that read